# How can I read a Google Spreadsheets using jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I have some information in Google Spreadsheets as a single sheet. Is there any way by which I can read this information from html by jquery and php. my sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/a/rangde.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0An6ySbpOsu3GdFlSZkt0TzZTWHJyblBiQlNrcmZvZGc&hl=en_US#gid=5) and my username suresh@rangde.org password Pattu&1991

Comment: Please also add your password so we can access the sheet.

Comment: Suresh change your password and never give to anybody again if you concern about your privacy. Your account is linked to your e-mails and etc. Anyone with your password can access your mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Google Spreadsheet API for PHP](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html)

OR

See [Simple example of retrieving JSON feeds from Spreadsheets Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample.html)